# Display Data from JSON Parse and Display it on Autocomplete Text Using Volley for Network

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

I have been trying to parse the json data from my rest API but could not succeed: 
Expected output: once I enter name in the autocomplete text, it should display a list of nearest name or names starting with that character and vice versa. It should work like auto complete text.
I have done a lot of research. pls help me out.
I dont know how to show the json value on autocomplete text.

I am getting json output, I parse the it using StringRequest but with no succes.

JSON:

```
[{"c_name":"Arafat"},{"c_name":"Krishna Naik"},{"c_name":"Samih kuttan"}]
```

Constructor code:

```
private String name;

public ListCustomer(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}`
```

Listname method for StringRequest:

```
public void ListCustomernames(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URLs.URL_listpopupwindow,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++){
                            //getting user object from json array

                            final JSONObject jsonObjec = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    //jsonObjec.getString("c_name");
                            ListCustomer listCustomer=new ListCustomer(
                                    jsonObjec.getString("c_name"));

                            responseList.add(listCustomer);

                        }


                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, responseList);
                        mVoiceInputTv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        mVoiceInputTv.setThreshold(1);
                        //ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,);
                       // mVoiceInputTv.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //stopping the swipeRefeshLayout
                    //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError  volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should probably be done like this.
                       JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

```
                    List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String name;
                    for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++){                         
                        name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("c_name");                             
                        responseList.add(name);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, responseList);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And also you can do like this

```
  List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();
                String name;
                for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++){                         
                    final JSONObject jsonObjec = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                //jsonObjec.getString("c_name");
                        ListCustomer listCustomer=new ListCustomer(
                                jsonObjec.getString("c_name"));                         
                    responseList.add(listCustomer.getName());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, responseList);
                mVoiceInputTv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Best way to do is

```
List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String name;
            List<ListCustomer> listnames=new ArrayList();
            for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++){                         
                final JSONObject jsonObjec = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            //jsonObjec.getString("c_name");
                    listnames.setName(jsonObjec.getString("c_name"));                         
                responseList.add(listnames.get(i).getName());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, responseList);
            mVoiceInputTv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) it really simplifies the JSON parsing